# По нажатию на один из items в RecyclerView открывается новый фрагмент

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, android-on-click

У меня есть `RecyclerView`, в нём есть `items`, мне нужно что бы по нажатию на какой либо из `item` происходил переход на новый `Fragment`,то есть у каждого `item` был свой `Fragment`. Также каждый `OnClick` нужно как-то привязать к позиции каждого `item` так как у меня есть сортировка. Как это сделать?

Мой `Fragment` с `RecyclerView`

```
public class FragmentAttractionRecyclerView extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "Fragment";
    private boolean firstPlayed = false;
    private RecyclerView mRec;
    private AttractionsAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<AttractionsItem> exampleList;
    
    private String[] mArrayNames = new String[]{"Виражи", "Вокруг света", "Интерактивный 5D кинотеатр", "Кокосовый страйк", "Компас"};
    private String[] mArrayCost = new String[]{"50₽", "75₽", "80₽", "85₽", "95₽", "100₽", "110₽", "120₽", "130₽", "160₽"};


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attraction_test_2, container, false);

    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        createExampleList();
        buildRecyclerView();
        CardView sort = requireView().findViewById(R.id.sort);
        
        sort.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: opening dialog");
            DialogSort dialog = new DialogSort();
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "DialogSort");
        });
    }

    public void createExampleList() {
        exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        exampleList.add(new AttractionsItem(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Baby островок", "Детский", "₽"));
        exampleList.add(new AttractionsItem(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Виражи", "Детский", "80₽"));
        exampleList.add(new AttractionsItem(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Вокруг света", "Детский", "50₽"));
        exampleList.add(new AttractionsItem(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_interactive, "5D кинотеатр", "Интерактивный", "120₽"));

    }
    
    public void buildRecyclerView() {
        mRec = requireView().findViewById(R.id.attraction_recycler);
        adapter = new AttractionsAdapter(exampleList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mRec.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRec.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

`Item`

```
public class AttractionsItem
{
    private int mImg_1,mImg_2;
    private String mTxt_1,mTxt_2,mTxt_3;
    public AttractionsItem(int img1,int img2, String txt_1, String txt_2, String txt_3)
    {
        mImg_1 = img1;
        mImg_2 = img2;

        mTxt_1 = txt_1;
        mTxt_2 = txt_2;
        mTxt_3 = txt_3;
    }
    public int getImg1()
    {
        return mImg_1;
    }
    public int getImg2()
    {
        return mImg_2;
    }
    public String getTxt_1()
    {
        return mTxt_1;
    }
    public String getTxt_2()
    {
        return mTxt_2;
    }
    public String getTxt_3()
    {
        return mTxt_3;
    }
}
```

`Adapter`

```
public class AttractionsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AttractionsAdapter.AttractionsViewHolder> {
    FragmentGyroLoop fragmentGyroLoop;
    public ArrayList<AttractionsItem> mFavList;

    public AttractionsAdapter(ArrayList<AttractionsItem> favList) {
        mFavList = favList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AttractionsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_attraction, parent, false);
        AttractionsViewHolder evh = new AttractionsViewHolder(v);
        return evh;

    }

    public static class AttractionsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView card_image_1, card_image_2;
        public TextView card_text_1, card_text_2, card_text_3;

        public AttractionsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            card_image_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_image_1);
            card_image_2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_image_2);
            card_text_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text_1);
            card_text_2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text_2);
            card_text_3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text_3);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AttractionsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        fragmentGyroLoop = new FragmentGyroLoop();
        AttractionsItem currentItem = mFavList.get(position);
        holder.card_image_1.setImageResource(currentItem.getImg1());
        holder.card_image_2.setImageResource(currentItem.getImg2());
        holder.card_text_1.setText(currentItem.getTxt_1());
        holder.card_text_2.setText(currentItem.getTxt_2());
        holder.card_text_3.setText(currentItem.getTxt_3());

        holder.card_image_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.transition_enter, R.anim.transition_exit,
                        R.anim.transition_enter, R.anim.transition_exit);
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment, fragmentGyroLoop, "detailFragment").addToBackStack( "tag" ).commit();
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFavList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вешайте случатель кликов в onBindViewHolder адаптера и всё

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я обновил вопрос, не правильно выразился мне нужно чтобы у каждого `item` был свой фрагмент. Если несложно могли бы вы подсказать как правильно написать такой код, или пример какой-нибудь скинуть?

Comment: В принципе, вам верно ответили уже. Если данные однотипны то в 99.7% случаев у вас должен быть один фрагмент. Если же нет - у вас есть вся необходимая инфа - AttractionsItem currentItem и position. Основываясь на них - пишите if-else и показывайте разные фрагменты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так.

```java
public AttractionsViewHolder(View itemView) {
    ...
    // Задать id CardView
    cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AttractionsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ...
    
    holder.card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Переход к фрагменту
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Вроде бы в таком случае `onClick` будет распространяться на все `CardView`. То есть по нажатию на любой из имеющихся  `CardView` будет перекидывать в один и тот же `Fragment`. А нужно что бы у каждого `CardView` был свой `Fragment`. И я попробовал написать так как вы посоветовали, но у меня ругается на `getActivity()`. Обновил вопрос

Comment: @buldog На сколько это необходимо? Правильнее использовать один макет для контент (ну или пару макетов, в зависимости от некоторых случаев). Просто при переходе во фрагмент передается ```id``` или весь ```item```.

Comment: А новый фрагмент для каждого `item` нельзя назначить? Просто в RecyclerView есть возможность легко сделать поисковую строку для `items`